# Nagios web interface access without slash at localhost

Tags: linux, ubuntu, localhost, lamp, nagios

How can I access the Nagios web interface without using the slash on a local host?
For example, when typing the IP address i need to access nagios. In other words, I don't want to use the slash, as follows: 192.168.123.122/nagios

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a base URL redirect match within Apache.

With that, going to http://192.168.123.122 will redirect you to http://192.168.123.122/nagios

In the file:

```
/etc/apache/apache2.conf
```

Add the following lines

```
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /nagios
 </Directory>
```

Restart Apache and you should be good to go.